# Styling/ Changing Autocomplete close Icon in Material UI React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, autocomplete

I wanted to change the icon in material UI's AutoComplete. I was not able to find any documentation to customize it.

Basically the two icons, marked with 1 and 2. I am new to Material Ui and would like to know if this can be done and how.

[image]

Codepen for the same is https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-9vhkq

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### Explain

If you check the DOM structure of it, you would find two button which have the class of something kind like

> className="MuiButtonBase-root MuiIconButton-root MuiAutocomplete-clearIndicator MuiAutocomplete-clearIndicatorDirty"
>   className="MuiButtonBase-root MuiIconButton-root MuiAutocomplete-popupIndicator"

Inside of them you can find the specific className

> MuiAutocomplete-clearIndicator
>   MuiAutocomplete-popupIndicator

Which you can refer to Material-UI Autocomplete css api [document](https://material-ui.com/api/autocomplete/#css)

> clearIndicator
>   popupIndicator

By setting styles to it, you can change it's styles, and the icons.

#### Code

```js
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    backgroundColor: "yellow"
  },
  clearIndicator: {
    backgroundColor: "gray",
    "& span": {
      "& svg": {
        "& path": {
          d: "path('M10 20v-6h4v6h5v-8h3L12 3 2 12h3v8z')" // your svg icon path here
        }
      }
    }
  },
  popupIndicator: {
    backgroundColor: "blue"
  }
}));
```

```js
    <Autocomplete
      id="combo-box-demo"
      options={top100Films}
      getOptionLabel={option => option.title}
      style={{ width: 300 }}
      classes={{
        clearIndicatorDirty: classes.clearIndicator,
        popupIndicator: classes.popupIndicator
      }}
```

Example:

[image: Edit condescending-oskar-2t15j]

Comment: So the Chevron is the popup indicator. Can the icon be changed?

Answer (score 10):

You can change the popup icon with the API using the **popupIcon** property:

```
popupIcon={<ImportContacts />}
```

Shows as:

[image: example of custom popup icon in mui AutoComplete]

Full API found here:
https://material-ui.com/api/autocomplete/