# Adding a prefix icon for the Antd Cascader

Tags: html, css, reactjs, antd

I am working with [antd cascader](https://ant.design/components/cascader/) and want to add a prefix icon in the cascader. Although there is a provision for a suffix icon in the cascader I could not find a way to add a prefix icon.

```
import { Cascader } from 'antd';

const options = [
    {
        value: 'zhejiang',
        label: 'Zhejiang',
        children: [
            {
                value: 'hangzhou',
                label: 'Hangzhou',
                children: [
                    {
                        value: 'xihu',
                        label: 'West Lake',
                    },
                ],
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        value: 'jiangsu',
        label: 'Jiangsu',
        children: [
            {
                value: 'nanjing',
                label: 'Nanjing',
                children: [
                    {
                        value: 'zhonghuamen',
                        label: 'Zhong Hua Men',
                    },
                ],
            },
        ],
    },
];

function onChange(value) {
    console.log(value);
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <Cascader options={options} onChange={onChange} placeholder="Please select" />,
    mountNode,
);
```

Currently, the cascader looks as :

[image]

I want it to look something similar to:

[image]

where the globe is a prefix icon. How could I add a prefix icon?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60179631/styling-changing-autocomplete-close-icon-in-material-ui-react/60179855#60179855

Comment: Does this example solve your issue? https://codesandbox.io/s/antd-cascader-n3vju .. Instead of ```ab``` text you can include icon..

Comment: @ManirajMurugan I need both the prefix and suffix icons

Comment: @keikai I need to also add the prefix icon with Antd cascader

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom cascader with prefix/suffix icons of your choice if you use a wrapper div with `relative` positioning and have the `<Icon/>` child with `absolute` positioning and higher `z-index` than the `Cascader/>` (to go on top of it).

Check the example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/antd-cascader-ynqpk

```
const CustomCascader = ({ options, width = 300 }) => {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

  const onChange = value => {
    console.log(value);
  };

  const filter = (inputValue, path) => {
    return path.some(
      option =>
        option.display_name.toLowerCase().indexOf(inputValue.toLowerCase()) > -1
    );
  };

  const onPopupVisibleChange = visible => {
    setOpen(visible);
  };

  return (
    <div style={{ position: "relative", width }}>
      <Icon
        type={open ? "up" : "down"}
        style={{ position: "absolute", right: 8, top: 10, zIndex: 5 }}
      />
      <Icon
        type="global"
        style={{ position: "absolute", left: 5, top: 10, zIndex: 5 }}
      />
      <Cascader
        style={{ paddingLeft: 0, width }}
        suffixIcon={<div />}
        expandTrigger="hover"
        fieldNames={{ label: "name", value: "code", children: "items" }}
        options={options}
        onChange={onChange}
        showSearch={{ filter }}
        placeholder="Please select"
        onPopupVisibleChange={onPopupVisibleChange}
        popupVisible={open}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    <CustomCascader options={options} />
    <CustomCascader options={options} />
    <CustomCascader options={options} />
  </div>,
  document.getElementById("container")
);
```